# Difference between NOTIFYICON_VERSION and NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4 used in NOTIFYICONDATA structure?

Tags: windows, winapi, system-tray, trayicon, shell32.dll

When adding a system tray icon from in Windows there are two versions of API that we can pass to `Shell_NotifyIcon()` via `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure. There are subtle differences between the two API, and these are not listed anywhere on MSDN. It took me some effort to figure out some of the differences, which I am going to share now. Improvements/additions to the answer are always welcome.

**PS:** This question is purely for sharing what I have learnt over last few days experimenting with windows DPI scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uVersion` member of the `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure can have 3 possible values, representing the version of the API being used to create the taskbar icon.

- **0** Use this value for applications designed for Windows versions prior to Windows 2000.
- **NOTIFYICON_VERSION** Use the Windows 2000 behavior. Use this value for applications designed for Windows 2000 and later.
- **NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4** Use the current behavior. Use this value for applications designed for Windows Vista and later.

When it comes to message handler for the tray icon, the `wParam`, and `uParam` have the differences as illustrated in the following image.

[image: NOTIFYICON_VERSION vs NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4]

Notice that in `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4` the wParam gives X, and Y coordinates of various events, but there is no provision for getting the coordinates in `NOTIFYICON_VERSION`. This gives rise to an interesting behaviour *(which was a cause of a BUG I was trying to solve)*. If you use `NOTIFYICON_VERSION`, and then invoke the context menu of the tray icon, then the mouse cursor, wherever it may be while you are invoking the menu, gets placed right at the center of the tray icon. Even if you use keyboard (**WINDOWS**+**B**) for invoking context menu of the icon, the mouse cursor still moves to the icon.

This may not be of particular interest to you until you look at this particular BUG I am trying to solve in [Pico torrent](https://github.com/picotorrent/picotorrent) application.

Here is the scenario.

- OS : Windows 10
- Application isn't per-monitor DPI aware, but is system level DPI aware.
- There is an initial value of Desktop scaling set, say 150%, when the user logs in.
- Pico torrent is running.
- DPI scaling value is changed to, say 125%
- Pico torrent's context menu is invoked
  The context menu will not be displayed at its proper place, and will be displaced a little, showing a deviance.

See the following images to understand what's happening.

[image: DPI scaling level : 150 %]
[image: DPI scaling level : 125 %]

The problem is that although [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx) says that `GET_X_LPARAM(wParam)`, and `GET_Y_LPARAM(wParam)` should give correct values in the handler of tray icon, but it doesn't, in the presence of DPI scaling (i.e. for a change in DPI scaling without doing a sign out and sign in). On the other hand the API `GetCursorPos()` returns the correct value of mouse cursor coordinates. Note that `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4` along with `GetCursorPos()` will not work, since the context menu can be invoked using keyboard, at which the mouse cursor can be anywhere on the screen(s).

So, how do you combine all the knowledge just learnt to display the tray icon's context menu correctly when DPI scaling is done in the manner above, without making you application per-monitor DPI aware (for per-monitor DPI aware applications `GET_X_LPARAM(wParam)`, and `GET_Y_LPARAM(wParam)` always return correct value)?

Use `NOTIFYICON_VERSION` instead of `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4`, this will position the mouse cursor at the tray icon when context menu is invoked, and then use `GetCursorPos()` to get mouse cursor's position. Display the context menu using `TrackPopupMenu()` with the coordinates.

**PS:** In the example above the DPI scaling value is changed from 150% to 125%. The context menu deviance is more pronounced when DPI scaling is done from a bigger value to a smaller value, when your tray icon area is on lower right of the screen. This is because when DPI scaling is done, and windows magnifies UI elements which are not per-monitor aware, using DPI virtualization, then things move right-wards, and down-wards. eg. if in an application a windows rectangle is (0,0,100,100) (screen coordinates), then after magnification to 150%, it may become (0,0,150,150). Now for tray icon's menu, if you specify coordinates which lie beyond bottom-right of the screen, then the OS will still display is at a bottom right position which lies inside the screen, and which ensures that menu is displayed properly. eg. if a screen is 1920x1080, and `TrackPopupMenu()`is given (10000,10000) for menu, the menu will still be displayed inside the 1920x1080 screen rectangle. Thus increasing DPI scaling will not move the context menu any further, if it has already reached the right-bottom most position.

Comment: The correct solution to the problem is to make the program DPI-aware. Dynamically load `SetProcessDpiAwareness()` at runtime if necessary.

Comment: Also note, when the tray icon popup is being invoked via keyboard, you can use [`Shell_NotifyIconGetRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378426(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the current screen position of the icon itself, instead of using `GetCursorPos()` to get the current screen position of the mouse.

Comment: @andlabs No it is not. Because if you make the process per monitor DPI aware, then you will have to handle scaling of every UI element yourself. Many developers still want to use DPI virtualization to some extent. Moreover if your application uses binary from a 3rd party, which creates UI elements, you will not be able to handle DPI scaling in it, since you do not have the code. This was the main reason which prompted Microsoft to introduce a new API in WIndows 10 Aniversary Update, SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext().

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, it doesn't work. I had tested that as well. You might want to check it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

@sahil-singh you are right about it, and I agree with everyone else that your application should be DPI aware, but when this is not a point here.

I had a similar issue where my application is (still) not DPI aware and GET_X_LPARAM(wParam) will return non-virtual coordinates. After passing this value to the TrackPopupMenu() I get wrong position on the screen.

The best way is to use GetMessagePos() instead of wParam. In this case, Windows will give you new DWORD with virtual coordinates and then use GET_X_LPARAM/GET_Y_LPARAM to get a values that you can pass to the TrackPopupMenu().

Comment: will GetMessagePos() work if your tray icon is invoked using the keyboard, and not the mouse ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to (2 years later in 2019) be [documented on MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_notifyicondataa)

> ## NOTIFYICONDATAA structure
>
> ### `uCallbackMessage`
>
> Type: **UINT**
>
> When the **uVersion** member is either 0 or NOTIFYICON_VERSION, the *wParam* parameter of the message contains the identifier of the taskbar icon in which the event occurred. This identifier can be 32 bits in length. The *lParam* parameter holds the mouse or keyboard message associated with the event. For example, when the pointer moves over a taskbar icon, *lParam* is set to [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645616(v=VS.85).aspx).
>
> When the **uVersion** member is NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4, applications continue to receive notification events in the form of application-defined messages through the **uCallbackMessage** member, but the interpretation of the *lParam* and *wParam* parameters of that message is changed as follows:
>
> - [LOWORD(lParam)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632659(v=VS.85).aspx) contains notification events, such as NIN_BALLOONSHOW, NIN_POPUPOPEN, or WM_CONTEXTMENU.
> - [HIWORD(lParam)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632657(v=VS.85).aspx) contains the icon ID. Icon IDs are restricted to a length of 16 bits.
> - [GET_X_LPARAM(wParam)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632654(v=VS.85).aspx) returns the X anchor coordinate for notification events NIN_POPUPOPEN, NIN_SELECT, NIN_KEYSELECT, and all mouse messages between WM_MOUSEFIRST and WM_MOUSELAST. If any of those messages are generated by the keyboard, wParam is set to the upper-left corner of the target icon. For all other messages, wParam is undefined.
> - [GET_Y_LPARAM(wParam)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632655(v=VS.85).aspx) returns the Y anchor coordinate for notification events and messages as defined for the X anchor.

Comment: Make sure to remove and re-add the notify icon in response to WM_DPICHANGED etc. Despite being per-monitor DPI aware, if my primary monitor is higher DPI than secondary, then if it becomes primary (by closing laptop lid for example) the WM_CONTEXTMENU notification wParam will always be offset! This drove me nuts for a while, but in the end you just have to remove and re-add the icon in response to that message to get it to reset.